# Is the Plaid /transactions/sync endpoint available in quickstart (i.e. for free users)?

Tags: plaid

I would like to make a get request to the transactions/sync endpoint to fetch my historical credit card data. However, I don't see the /transactions/sync endpoint in the quickstart/python/server.py file. I only see /api/transaction. Am I missing something or are some endpoints only available in paid tiers?

I have looked through the server.py file and the documentation on the Plaid website but its unclear to me whether all the transaction endpoints are supposed to be available.

Answer (score 0):

/api/transactions is not a Plaid API endpoint, it is an endpoint that is internal to the sample app. If you look at its actual implementation in the QuickStart you will find that it calls /transactions/sync

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with the Plaid customer support team and this was their answer:

> Each of the backend servers in the Quickstart application has endpoints (like `/api/transactions`) that are requested by the frontend page when you run a front and backend at the same time. Within the code for each of the `/api` endpoints, you'll see requests being made to Plaid's API via built-in methods that are provided by the client libraries.